# How to create and access value of controller for different TextFormFields in ListView Builder inside Future Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I'm creating an Edit Products form in which the data is being fetched from api and populate inside the future builder.
As of saving new data from the `TextFormField`, I will need different `Controllers`.

It have different TextFields for `Product name` `Product price` and `Product Description`

So what I'm trying to say is that as if there are multiple products, there will be multiple `Product name` TextFields and it will have multiple controllers.

So what I want to achieve is that how can I access the values of different `Controllers` in one `List` on button click.

Suppose if there are 4 different products like `Furniture` `Window Glass` `Artificial Grass` and`Modular kitchen` and when user click on save button all these values should get in one list and then send to database.

**This is what I've tried**

```
var productNameControllers = [];
```

I've populated this list inside the Future Builder and assigned the controllers to textfields

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: _showData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                    productNameControllers.add(TextEditingController(
                        text: snapshot.data[index].prodSerName.toString()));
                  
                 return Container(
                    child: TextFormField(
                   controller: productNameControllers[index],
                   decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Product Name",
                ),
            ),
                 );
});
}
});
```

And this is the code for accessing the controller

```
  _saveEdits() {
    List savedProds = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < productNameControllers.length; i++) {
      savedProds.add(productNameControllers[i].text);
    }
    print(savedProds);
  }
```

So the problem is that when the `_saveEdits` method is called It only access the first two controller values instead of all the values and when I'm scrolling the page to the last product and then calling the `_saveEdits` method then it works correctly but why It is not accessing all the values without scrolling to the last item.

**The output I want**

To access all the values
`[Furniture, Window glass, Artificial Grass, Modular Kitchen]`

**The output I got**

Only first two values
`[Furniture, Window glass]`

So how can I achieve it.

**After Replacing ListView.builder with Listview**

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: _showData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.map((val) {
                final int index = snapshot.data.indexOf(val);
                productNameControllers
                    .add(TextEditingController(text: val.prodSerName));

                return Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: productNameControllers[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Product Name",
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList());
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
            }
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView.builder does some optimizations such as only holding the objects that are displayed in the UI at that moment, not all values which is a good thing

I would recommend that do not use the builder but use the default ListView and do something like the following

```
ListView(
children: snapshot.data.map(
(val) {
 
 final int index = snapshot.data.indexOf(val);
 productNameControllers.add(TextEditingController(
                    text: val.prodSerName.toString()));
              
             return Container(
                child: TextFormField(
               controller: productNameControllers[index],
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Product Name",
            ),
        ),
             );
}
).toList()
```

Comment: After replacing `ListView.builder` with `ListView` I'm getting this error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<TextEditingController>' of 'function result'
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<Data>>
lib\products-services.dart:205`

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: I've added code in the edit